# How would you do this task using SQL or R library sqldf?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, r

I need to implement the following function (ideally in R or SQL): given two data frames (have a column for userid and the rest of the colums are booleans attributes (they are just permitted to be 0's or 1's)) I need to return a new data frame with two  columns (userid and count) where count is the number of matches for 0's and 1's for each user in both tables. An user F could occur in both data frames or it could occur in just one. In this last case, I need to return NA for that user count. I write an example:

```
DF1
ID c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1   0  1  0  1  1
10  1  0  1  0  0
5   0  1  1  1  0
20  1  1  0  0  1
3   1  1  0  0  1
6   0  0  1  1  1
71  1  0  1  0  0
15  0  1  1  1  0
80  0  0  0  1  0

DF2  
ID c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
5   1  0  1  1  0
6   0  1  0  0  1
15  1  0  0  1  1
80  1  1  1  0  0
78  1  1  1  0  0
98  0  0  1  1  1
1   0  1  0  0  1
2   1  0  0  1  1
9   0  0  0  1  0
```

My function must return something like this: (the following is a subset)

```
DF_Return
ID Count
1    4
2    NA
80   1
20   NA
   .
   .
   .
```

Could you give me any suggestions to carry this out? I'm not that expert in sql.

I put the codes in R to generate the experiment I used above.

```
 id1=c(1,10,5,20,3,6,71,15,80)
 c1=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0)
 c2=c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0)
 c3=c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0)
 c4=c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)
 c5=c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0)
 DF1=data.frame(ID=id1,c1=c1,c2=c2,c3=c3,c4=c4,c5=c5)
 DF2=data.frame(ID=c(5,6,15,80,78,98,1,2,9),c1=c2,c2=c1,c3=c5,c4=c4,c5=c3)
```

Many thanks in advance.
Best Regards!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? ..

Comment: Hello, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach for you. The first hardcodes the columns to compare, while the other is more general and agnostic to how many columns DF1 and DF2 have:

```
#Merge together using ALL = TRUE for equivlent of outer join
DF3 <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = "ID", all = TRUE, suffixes= c(".1", ".2"))
#Calculate the rowSums where the same columns match
out1 <- data.frame(ID = DF3[, 1], count = rowSums(DF3[, 2:6] ==  DF3[, 7:ncol(DF3)]))

#Approach that is agnostic to the number of columns you have
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
DF3.m <- melt(DF3, id.vars = 1)
DF3.m[, c("level", "DF")] <- with(DF3.m, colsplit(variable, "\\.", c("level", "DF")))
out2 <- dcast(data = DF3.m, ID + level ~ DF, value.var="value")
colnames(out)[3:4] <- c("DF1", "DF2")
out2 <- ddply(out, "ID", summarize, count = sum(DF1 == DF2))

#Are they the same?
all.equal(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE

> head(out1)
  ID count
1  1     4
2  2    NA
3  3    NA
4  5     3
5  6     2
6  9    NA
```

Comment: one more question @Chase... could you give me how this approach changes if I need now the counts of 0's and 1's separately, i.e, I need a new data frame with three columns, The userid and the count for 0's and 1's. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(DF1.ID, DF2.ID)  AS ID,
  CASE WHEN DF1.c1 = DF2.c1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN DF1.c2 = DF2.c2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN DF1.c3 = DF2.c3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN DF1.c4 = DF2.c4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN DF1.c5 = DF2.c5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count_of_matches
FROM
  DF1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  DF2
    ON DF1.ID = DF2.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a more elegant way, but this works:

```
x <- merge(DF1,DF2,by="ID",all=TRUE)
pre <- paste("c",1:5,sep="")
x$Count <- rowSums(x[,paste(pre,"x",sep=".")]==x[,paste(pre,"y",sep=".")])
DF_Return <- x[,c("ID","Count")]
```

Comment: Quite similar approaches we have here...lets me know i'm somewhat on the right path! +1

Comment: @Chase: agreed. I like your more general solution though.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `safe_full_join` from my package [*safejoin*](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/safejoin), and apply `==`
between conflicting columns. This will yield a new data frame with logical
`c*` columns that we can use `rowSums` on.

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)

safe_full_join(DF1, DF2, by = "ID", conflict = `==`) %>%
  transmute(ID, count = rowSums(.[-1]))
#    ID count
# 1   1     4
# 2  10    NA
# 3   5     3
# 4  20    NA
# 5   3    NA
# 6   6     2
# 7  71    NA
# 8  15     1
# 9  80     1
# 10 78    NA
# 11 98    NA
# 12  2    NA
# 13  9    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` function to handle this. To get the sum of each row, you can use:

```
sums <- apply(df1[2:ncol(df1)], 1, sum)
cbind(df1[1], sums)
```

which will return the sum of all but the first column, then bind that to the first column to get the ID back.

You could do that on both data frames. I'm not really clear what the desired behavior is after that, but maybe look at the `merge` function.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Allen, but That's not what I need. I think you've misunderstood my question.

Comment: `rowSums(DF1[, -1])` will prove faster as well.